# Azure VMSS Customscript extension execution monitoring with Azure Monitor

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

In some instances when executing custom script extension on Linux/Windows VMSS the execution fails may be for timeout or evening invalid file uris or invalid Storage Access Token. Is there a way using Azure monitor that I can capture this failure event so that I can trigger operational activities such as sending emails to the ops teams.

Answer (score 0):

The VM Extension Provisioning Error failure events will pop up on the Activity Logs. So you can [send the activity logs similar to Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log#send-to-log-analytics-workspace) from the VM(s) to enable features of [Azure Monitor Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-platform-logs)

Activity log data in a Log Analytics workspace is stored in a table called AzureActivity that you can retrieve with a [log query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-query-overview) in [Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-tutorial). The structure of this table varies depending on the [category of the log entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log-schema). For a description of the table properties, see the [Azure Monitor data reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/azureactivity).

For example you can filter

```
AzureActivity
| where * contains "VMExtensionProvisioningError"
```

Please ensure to add additional filters as required.

You can [set up your log alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal) based on this.